# Let $N_n = \# \{k \le n: X_k = 6\}$. Establish the almost sure convergence of the sequence $(N_n / n)_{n \geq 1}$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Hi I'm having trouble finding the almost sure convergence of this problem:

> Consider a succession of tosses of a balanced die. Let $X_k$ be the result of the $k$-th face and $Y_n = \max(X_k), k ≤ n.$ 
> Let $N_n = \# \{k \le n: X_k = 6\}$. Establish the almost sure convergence of the sequence $(N_n / n)_{n \geq 1}$.

I know that in order to prove almost sure convergence I nedd to show that
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)\right)=1$$

But I can't seem to find a way to use it

Can someone help me?

Comment: Just apply SLLN to the sequence $(I_{\{X_k=6\}})$

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $N_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=1} I_k$, where $I_k \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(1/6)$ represents the outcome of the $k$th dice toss (i.e. $I_k = 1$ if $X_k = 6$ with probability $1/6$, and $I_k = 0$ otherwise). Each $I_k$ is independent. Furthermore, $\mathbb{E}[I_k] = 1/6$.

Hence, by the [Strong Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law), the sample mean of the i.i.d. random variables $I_k$ will converge almost surely to their common mean. That is, $N_n \to \frac{1}{6}$ a.s.

This should align with what $N_n$ intuitively represents -- the ``average'' number of $6$s you see in $n$ tosses.